# Trying to simulate channel length modulation effects to see practical considerations, finding negligible results

Tags: transistors, mosfet, analog

I'm a beginner, self-learning electronics, currently studying MOSFETS and I have been recently [introduced to channel length modulation effects.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jfizMWm3Q0I&list=PLunAuxHqEAijgoKKoo7aYYvXtjiVwbin5&index=4) I understand the theory behind it but after some simulations I'm confused about why I should care or if it's something that affects some MOSFETS more than others.

I did a [falstad simulation](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEB2B0DMzIBYBMZcEFsEA2MbEBSKkbdKgUwFowwAoAMxHVxr4AcPAZUE9c4aEhiRc7AErj+kIYVIgxNGthrSoUKQuGU2E9CJClKNBmBphS0UVoMJ2AJ2PgCXsAE4Je3YAcy9cZDMLXhdIdh0GbCtwXCEsSnQcfUgAfWxsnOwHdGywKVJcbD8q6pq-ARYwZBLoQgaBfOzcDvR2AHcwiLCK8HZzDRAAMQgXPhBWEABZAEMADwAdAGcANQB7ABsAFyXgxlHVSYhAjRp5gBEAYU2AeU5ODcYD9iA) and found no channnel length modulation effects whatsoever. I concluded that probably this simulation just ignores the effect so I made a similar circuit on LtSpice using a [BS170](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mmbf170-d.pdf) (for no particular reason, just picked some popular MOSFET) and I found the channel length modulation effect to be just 400 nA for the whole amplitude of the MOSFET's acceptable voltage range (Vds)

[image]

**The question:**
Is this what channel length modulation normaly looks like? Does it become much more noticable under some circumstances or with other MOSFETS? Why would I care for such a small effect? I'm a beginner and this to me looks like almost noise-level small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct that Falstad doesn't seem to simulate channel-length modulation. The falstad model seems to only have two parameters - threshold voltage, and the leading factor in the square-law equation, so it cannot express channel-length modulation.

Channel-length modulation is most applicable in shorter-channel MOSFETs and especially transistors operated in strong inversion (strong gate drive). The BS170 has a fairly flat I-Vds characteristic in its datasheet (see Figure 1), suggesting that it doesn't suffer from channel length modulation very severely.

On the other hand, here's an example of how short-channel FETs (used in CMOS integrated circuits) look in a similar simulation:

[image]

Red is on the order of 500-100 nm long, yellow is 50-100 nm long, and teal on the order of 5-10 microns long. All are nFETs in the same CMOS process. Your discrete transistor is likely significantly longer given its much higher maximum voltage ratings. The X scale spans the entire working voltage range for this particular transistor.

You can see that the two shorter ones visibly suffer from channel-length modulation and other short-channel effects which are not distinguishable on an IV plot (since they look like an effective output impedance in both cases), but have different physical causes.

Unfortunately due to NDA, I'm not comfortable sharing the exact dimensions or exact numerical scale of the chart.

To replicate the same in LT-Spice, you may be able to search for an integrated design SPICE model deck, perhaps along the lines of 180 nm (a popular choice for teaching).

Comment: does this mean that generally speaking, the longer the channel the more I can ignore channel length modulation effects? so in discrete mosfets the effect would be negligible most of the time?

Comment: @JoaquinBrandan Not always: silicon carbide FETs typically have a pretty short channel, so if you use SiC MOSFETs you may need to consider it. Though I don't think people generally use them for linear applications!

Comment: @JoaquinBrandan Yes, generally speaking that's the case. I still recommend checking the datasheet to get a sense for any given part since there may be tricks for power FETs that I'm not aware of given my background in tiny FETs used in linear applications (like the SiC example Hearth brings up)

Comment: @JoaquinBrandan Another thing that I'm just remembering now - some discrete FETs are intended for small-signal use and may have thin channels. e.g. https://www.aldinc.com/pdf/ALD1108E.pdf seems to have a 14k effective output impedance at quick glance (see HIGH LEVEL OUTPUT CONDUCTANCE
vs.THRESHOLD VOLTAGE in that datasheet)